# Не могу вернуть из функции подключение к базе данных;

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function getConnection()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'example');

    return $conn;
}

getConnection();


var_dump($conn);
```

Подскажите, как правильно вернуть поток соединения с БД из функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция возвращает значение. Присваивайте его переменной

```
$conn = getConnection();
```

Comment: Благодарю!Очень помогли, был не внимателен.

Answer (score 2):

Данная функция не имеет смысла если ее применять правильно, и принесет очень много вреда, если применять так, как задумано.

Подключение к БД должно происходить в скрипте **строго один раз.** После этого полученный объект должен использоваться для выполнения всех запросов в приложении.

То есть единственный правильный вариант использования этой функции будет

```
function getConnection()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'example');
    return $conn;
}
$conn = getConnection();
```

что, разумеется можно сократить до простого

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'example');
```

Если же планируется вызывать эту функуцию в любом месте, где потребуется соединение с БД, это приведет к открытию десятков соединений, что достаточно быстро угробит сервер, даже при небольшом трафике.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас функция возвращает значение. Где Вы его используете? Код должен быть такой

```
$conn = getConnection();
var_dump($conn);
```